# Adjusting dates and adding new rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to calculate the difference between dates but in order to separate them out correctly by month I am hoping to add new rows instead of have a column for each month. I need the following:

If the month of a start date [ss_strt_dtd] equal the month of the end date [ss_end_dtd] then nothing needs to happen.

However, if the the months differ then I need the start date to remain the same but the end date to be the first date of the new month. Then a new start date in the first of the month and the end date to remain the same.

Example:

```
January 15, 2018 - January 18, 2018 - Nothing needs to happen
January 28, 2018 - February 2, 2018 would need to be split into two
```

rows that look like this:

```
[ss_strt_dtd]01/28/2018  [ss_end_dtd]02/01/2018
[ss_strt_dtd]02/01/2018 [ss_end_dtd]02/02/2018
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNION:

```
select ss_strt_dtd, ss_end_dtd from [S&S_Combined]
where year(ss_strt_dtd) = year(ss_end_dtd) and month(ss_strt_dtd) = month(ss_end_dtd)
union all
select ss_strt_dtd, DateSerial(year(ss_end_dtd), month(ss_end_dtd), 1) from [S&S_Combined]
where year(ss_strt_dtd) <> year(ss_end_dtd) or month(ss_strt_dtd) <> month(ss_end_dtd)
UNION ALL select DateSerial(year(ss_end_dtd), month(ss_end_dtd), 1), ss_end_dtd from [S&S_Combined]
where year(ss_strt_dtd) <> year(ss_end_dtd) or month(ss_strt_dtd) <> month(ss_end_dtd);
```

Comment: It states there is a syntax error in the FROM clause

Comment: Is your table's name `S&S_Combined`?

Comment: See my edited answer, the name of your table must be enclosed inside brackets, like `[S&S_Combined]` because it contains the char `&`.

Comment: I updated it but now it states Compile error, in query expression

Comment: I tested it and there is no error. Copy and paste the above code as it is.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had to go to VBA and remove the error because it kept giving me a compile error. I was hoping you'd be able to help. I'm not sure where to put it but I also need to grab the column called docno. I tried to put it in the beginning but it said there was an error when doing the union.

Comment: If this column is also in the table `S&S_Combined` then add it let's say 1st in all 3 parts of this union query (It must be at the same position in every part).

Answer (score 0):

You can this with a set of queries that also will work if the timespan covers many months.

First a small query to return 10 numbers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM MSysObjects;
```

Save this as **Ten**.

Then a query to return a the series of months in your date interval:

```
PARAMETERS 
    [DateStart] DateTime, 
    [DateEnd] DateTime;
SELECT 
    [Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000 AS Id, 
    [DateStart] AS DateStart,
    [DateEnd] AS DateEnd, 
    DateAdd("m",[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000,[DateStart]) AS DateMonth
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, 
    Ten AS Ten_1, 
    Ten AS Ten_2, 
    Ten AS Ten_3, 
    Ten AS Ten_4, 
    Ten AS Ten_5, 
    Ten AS Ten_6
WHERE 
    (((DateAdd("m",
        [Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000,
        [DateStart]))<=DateAdd("m",
        DateDiff("m", [DateStart],DateAdd("d",-1,[DateEnd])),[DateStart])) 
    AND ((Ten_0.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\1) 
    AND ((Ten_1.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\10) 
    AND ((Ten_2.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\100) 
    AND ((Ten_3.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\1000) 
    AND ((Ten_4.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\10000) 
    AND ((Ten_5.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\100000) 
    AND ((Ten_6.N)<=DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])\1000000));
```

Save this as **MonthsDateRange**.

Finally, calculate the *From* and *To* dates for each month respecting the start and end date:

```
SELECT 
    MonthsDateRange.Id, 
    MonthsDateRange.DateStart, 
    MonthsDateRange.DateEnd, 
    Year([DateMonth]) AS [Year], 
    Month([DateMonth]) AS [Month], 
    IIf(DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateMonth])=0,
        [DateStart],
        DateSerial(Year([DateMonth]),Month([DateMonth]),1)) AS DateFrom, 
    IIf(DateDiff("m",[DateEnd],[DateMonth])=0,
        [DateEnd],
        DateSerial(Year([DateMonth]),Month([DateMonth])+1,1)) AS DateTo, 
    DateDiff("d",[DateFrom],[DateTo]) AS Days
FROM 
    MonthsDateRange;
```

Save this as **DaysMonthsDateRange**.

It will return something like this:

[image: Example output]

Note, that the query is designed to be able to return the months of the entire range of data type *Date*.

That is 118800 records from 100-01-01 to 9999-12-31.